# How to timeout long running deployment for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am using Tomcat as an application server for my REST APIs. I initiate a data grid connection as a servlet while deploying each WAR file. In some cases, when I am trying to restart Tomcat and the data grid is down, my deployment waits until the server is down.

Is there a way I can set timeouts on deployment so that they can block the Tomcat server start up?